# Code re-executes after window closes

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import*
from random import radint
Characters=[Percy,Annabeth,Leo,Chuck,Sarah]
Used = []
def callback():
    selected = None
    end = len(Characters)-1
    rando = randint(0,end)
    selected = Characters[rando]
    for i in Characters:
        if i in Used:
            print 'This has already been used'
        else:
            Characters[rando]()
            Used.append(Characters[rando])


game = Tk()
game.geometry('50x50+700+100')
Button1 = Button(game,text = '1',command =lambda:callback() )
Button1.pack(side=LEFT)


game.mainloop()
```

What is supposed to happen is, the program runs, 1 button is in the window, you click the button,it randomly selects one of the values from the list 'Characters' (all of which are procedures), executes the procedure and then adds selected value to the list 'Used', then when you click the button again, it checks if that value has already been used, and if it has, it prints 'This has already been used' if it has not, it executes.
But what is happening, is that it will run the same procedure multiple times, and then when I close the root window (game) it re-executes all of the procedures that were executed when I hit my button.I have been working at this for an hour and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in Characters:` goes through all of the items in the list `Characters` each time it is run.

Suppose you start up your app, and click the button. This is what happens:

```
for i in Characters:

    i = Percy
    if i in Used: 
        ... #i is not in Used
    else:
        ... #execute Percy() and add it to Used

    i = Annabeth
    if i in Used:
        ... #i is not in Used

    else:
        ... #execute Annabeth() and add it to Used
```

...you get the picture. So the 1st time it is run, all of the characters are executed, and added to `Used`.

You should probably change that code to something like this:

```
def callback():
    # code ...

    rando = randint(0, end)
    if Characters[rando] in Used:
        print "This has already been used"
    else:
        Characters[rando]()
        Used.append(Characters[rando])
```

Comment: That is the exact code I had before I had the `for` loop, but it would run the same procedure multiple times.

Comment: @ChuckFulminata : Are you saying that it will select the same character multiple times? As in it runs `Percy()` for example, and then attempt to run Percy again (failing of course, because it's already been used) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the very first time you click the button it will add all of the characters to the list. It may appear it happens when your program ends, but it's actually happening all at once.

Assuming you want to process a single instance of Character on each click, you need to add a `break` statement to terminate your loop after appending something to the list.

```
for i in Characters:
    if i in Used:
        print 'This has already been used'
    else:
        Characters[rando]()
        Used.append(Characters[rando])
        break
```